# R How to deal with unexpected quantity of new levels with glm

Tags: r, prediction, glm, predict, missing-features

Here is my problem. I have a GLM model based on old data.
My newdata have the same explicative variables, but with more levels.
I want to give a fix a beta value to each explicative variables with new level.
For example, imagine that the input 'A' have a new level called 'ANew'. By using the `predict(*)`
R function, I want to predict a beta of `0.12` for this input. The input 'B' have a new level called
'BNew'. I want to predict a beta of `0.5` for this input, and so on...